# springboot not mapping endpoints defined in another module

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot to build a spring mvc application. The MyApplication and MyController are in different modules, with dependencies added to pom, and when I run it, the mapping defined below (/greet) is not being mapped to dispacherServlet, while if the both classes in the same package, the endpoint gets mapped.

MyApplication.java

```
package com.test;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
}}
```

pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <modules>
 <module>controller</module>
</modules>

 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.test.MyApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

MyController.java

```
package com.test.controllers;

@RestController         
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/greet")
        public String greeting()
        {
            return "HELLO THERE";
        }
```

Comment: When they are in different modules do they both have the same package name com.test.controllers or did you get that package name while testing it in the same module and it's different in the other module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved by adding module dependency onto the required projects, by going into "Project Structure" in intelliJ and adding the required dependencies, everything worked. An simple overlooked mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Try Adding a component scan annotation

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.test.controllers"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
}}
```